# Volley POST request not working on Android after updating PHP backend to Slim 4

Tags: android, android-volley, slim

I have a sign in script for our Android app. It uses Volley 1.1.1 and has worked fine for year but after switching our PHP backend from Slim 3 to Slim 4, it's no longer working.

```
public Map<String,String> loginUser(String uemail, String upassword, final AuthAsyncResponse callBack) {

    String url = "https://myendpoint.com/auth/signin";
    Map<String,String> userData = new HashMap<>();

    final HashMap<String, String> postParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

    Log.d(TAG, "login status uemail: " + uemail);
    Log.d(TAG, "login status upassword: " + upassword);

    postParams.put("email", uemail);
    postParams.put("password", upassword);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            url,
            new JSONObject(postParams),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    
                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: response");

                        // ... sign in tasks
                        // ... build a user data object

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d(TAG, "login status: ", e);
                    }

                    Log.d(TAG, "failed ");

                    if (null != callBack) callBack.processFinished(userData);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("LOG", "login status onErrorResponse: " + error);
                }
            }
    )
    {
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }
    };

    AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().clear();
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);

    return userData;

}
```

I am able to log the initial uemail and upassword variables, which tells me the function is running. However, once I call new JsonObjectRequest, nothing happens. I don't get any of the log messages I put in the try catch block or in the error listener. I also don't get any run time errors.

If I change the endpoint to a site running Slim 3, the script works, however with Slim 4 it doesn't.

I have tried the endpoint with Postman and I'm able to get a response with the necessary data back.

GET requests seem to be working fine.

What could have changed so that the script stopped working all of a sudden?

Comment: Does your backend communicates to a different domain? If yes, have you checked the CORS handling / headers on the server side?

Comment: @odan backend does not communicate with a different domain.

Answer (score 0):

According to this page: https://akrabat.com/receiving-input-into-a-slim-4-application/

I needed to add this line

```
$app->addBodyParsingMiddleware();
```

to my Slim app.